# Get data from PHP array via AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have a page as below:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#prev').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: 'id=testdata',
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
    $('#content1').html(result[0]);
  },
  });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="prev">prev</td>
<td id="content1">X</td>
<td id="next">next</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

and a php file `ajax.php` to handle ajax requests as;

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo $array;
?>
```

But when I click, I am getting `A` instead of array[0]. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

you cannot access array (php array) from js
try

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

and js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#prev').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: 'id=testdata',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#content1').html(result[0]);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 26):

quite possibly the simplest method ...

```
<?php
$change = array('key1' => $var1, 'key2' => $var2, 'key3' => $var3);
echo json_encode(change);
?>
```

Then the jquery script ...

```
<script>
$.get("location.php", function(data){
var duce = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var art1 = duce.key1;
var art2 = duce.key2;
var art3 = duce.key3;
});
</script>
```

Comment: + 1 for `jQuery.parseJSON(data);` solved my problems !!

Comment: Just a note. jQuery.parseJSON is deprecated in latest versions of JQuery. Use JSON.parse instead.

Comment: spent hours trying to figure this out. My mistake was I had to parse the json THEN try to access the keys.

Answer (score 8):

When you `echo $array;`, the result is `Array`, `result[0]` then represents the first character in `Array` which is `A`.

One way to handle this problem would be like this:

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($array as $a)
    echo $a.",";
?>
```

**jquery code**

```
$(function(){ /* short for $(document).ready(function(){ */

    $('#prev').click(function(){

        $.ajax({type:    'POST',
                 url:     'ajax.php',
                 data:    'id=testdata',
                 cache:   false,
                 success: function(data){
                     var tmp = data.split(",");
                     $('#content1').html(tmp[0]);
                 }
                });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

you cannot access array (php array) from js try

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo implode('~',$array);
?>
```

and js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#prev').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: 'id=testdata',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    result=data.split('~');
    $('#content1').html(result[0]);
  },
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `echo $array;`, PHP will simply echo 'Array' since it can't convert an array to a string. So The 'A' that you are actually getting is the first letter of Array, which is correct.

You might actually need

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

This should get you what you want.

**EDIT** : And obviously, you'd need to change your JS to work with JSON instead of just text (as pointed out by @genesis)

Comment: @genesis, you're right of course. Noted in the answer, thanks.