# How can I retrieve multiple echoes in my PHP to my success:function

Tags: php, html, jquery

in my php I echoed

```
        //sql query here
        foreach($user as $values){
            echo $values['id'];
            echo $values['name'];
            echo $values['email'];
            echo $values['loc'];
        }
```

in my $.post

```
success:function(msg){
//what to put here to be able to retrieve the values?
}
```

and in my html

```
 <td id="idField"></td><td id="nameField"></td><td id="emailField"></td><td id="locField"></td>
```

How should be done in a right way? The output should display the specified columns from a table and should display a numbers of rows depends from the query result.

Comment: have you made any research how to do it? how to pass variables via $.post?

Comment: Instead of echo'ing the variables directly like that, do one echo with `json_encode($values);` From there, you should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: yes but I only find like $(#id).html(msg) but this only applicable for 1 echo?

Comment: and im planning to put it to a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP

```
echo json_encode($user);
```

jQuery

```
success:function(msg){
  $('#idField').html(msg.id);
  $('#nameField').html(msg.name;
  // etc      
}
```

You really should learn how to use documentation, google, SO and online help. There is thousands of tutorials, docs, help how to do it. Just make some research before you ask for help.

> [Get data from php array - AJAX - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395720/get-data-from-php-array-ajax-jquery)