# PHP array to JavaScript using jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I want to manipulate a PHParray in javascript. This is the code i'm using.

Array.php

```
<?php

$sentido[1]="ver";
$sentido[2]="tocar";
$sentido[3]="oir";
$sentido[4]="gustar";
$sentido[5]="oler"; 


?>
```

fx_funciones.js

```
 /*Pre-sentences*/
 var js_array=new Array();

$.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "array.php",
       success: function(response) {
           js_array=response      
       }
    });
```

This is what I want to do but it's not working.

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything with the array after you create it. Try adding `echo json_encode($sentido)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get data from php array - AJAX - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395720/get-data-from-php-array-ajax-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , the answer for above question is already addressed in below link. please check them out.
[Get data from php array - AJAX - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395720/get-data-from-php-array-ajax-jquery)

I hope it will help you

Comment: If you think an existing question and its answers provide the answer for this question then you should flag the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$sentido[1]="ver";
$sentido[2]="tocar";
$sentido[3]="oir";
$sentido[4]="gustar";
$sentido[5]="oler"; 

echo json_encode($sentido);
```

And:

```
$.getJSON('array.php', function(sentido) {
    console.log(sentido);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to return the array from your PHP code as JSON, using the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. Then, in your jQuery code, specify a `json` dataType so that it's implicitly converted and passed to the callback function as an array:

```
var js_array=new Array();

$.ajax({        
   type: "POST",
   url: "array.php",
   success: function(response) {
       js_array=response      
   },
   dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard JSON notation. It serializes objects and arrays. Then print it, fetch it on the client and parse it.

On the server:

```
echo json_encode($sentido);
```

For more on PHP's json_encode: http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

On the client, this is specially easy if you use the jQuery function for ajax that expect JSON-encoded objects, and parses them for you:

```
$.getJSON('address/to/your/php/file.php', function(sentidos) {

    alert(sentidos[0]);  // It will alert "ver"
    alert(sentidos[1]);  // It will alert "tocar"

});
```

It uses GET but this most probably what you need.

For more on jQuery's $.getJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/