# Syntax difficulties in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function connected with onclick button.
It sends some data through ajax to another php file.
Actually everything was working fine, but I tried to add now to 'success' a simple IF statement, that would get true or false from external file.
I guess some of the syntax may be wrong here because the error message says that my main fuction is not defined.
**Could someone find some mistakes here please?**

main file **(here in success: i have added if else statement only)**:

```
              $.ajax({
              type: 'get',
              url: '/editcomment',
              data: {newComment: newComment,
                             id: id,
                         userId: userId},

              success:function(data){
                  if(data.success){
                       $(".newCommentForm" +id).replaceWith("<span id='" + id + "' class='limitedText'>" + newComment + "</span>");
                       $(thisId).data("PinComment", newComment);
                   } 
                   else { alert('error');},

              error:function(){
                       alert('error');
                     }
          });                     
      }
```

external file **(i have added the return arrays here)**:

```
public function editComment(){

   $userId = Input::get('userId');   

   if ( $userId == Auth::id() or Auth::user()->hasRole("admin")){

      $id = Input::get('id');
      $newComment = Input::get('newComment');
      DB::update('UPDATE `comments` SET f_text = ? WHERE h_id = ?', array($newComment, $id));
      return array('success' => true);

     } else {
         return array('success' => false);
     }    
}
```

Comment: your given code and description is not clear and complete

Comment: It's difficult to explain the whole project :D I just have some syntax problem in the ajax

Comment: Even with this simple returned data I would suggest you used `echo json_encode(array('success' => false));` and return your data as a json string. It makes everything easier to use in javascript. Also add `dataType : 'json'` to your `$.ajax` parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here `else { alert('error');},`, you need another closing brace to close the success function.

Comment: And also a `)` so you need `})`

Comment: Well i have edited my post giving some more code from this ajax coz the brace was already there.
But thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access PHP array in JS that not possible. What you need to do is, either you need to return response as an string or JSON from PHP file

see: [Get data from php array - AJAX - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395720/get-data-from-php-array-ajax-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of commas. Try this in else block

```
jAlert('No Success', 'alert box');
```